# Derived classes as class constructor parameters

Tags: scala, inheritance

[EDITED BELOW]

I have a class hierarchy that is, right now, roughly as follows:

```
sealed trait Foo {
  def method: Any
}

case class Bar extends Foo {
  def method: Array[String] = // implementation
}

case class Baz extends Foo {
  def method: Map[String, Array[String]] = // implementation
}
```

I am giving the abstract method a return type of `Any` because the return types of the case classes are necessarily different, but they share a similar purpose.  For this reason, I'd like to keep it in the trait to model that common behavior, and this is the only way I've found to make it compile.  I realize this is against the spirit of Scala's type system, so I ask the first question below.

Then, another class expects a subclass of `Foo` as a constructor parameter, and I do not know how to denote this, other than the following:

```
class Qux(foo: Foo) {
  val m = foo.method
  ...
  ...
}
```

Later in the class `Qux` there are methods that expect the val `m` to be of the type corresponding to the particular subclass (`Bar` or `Baz`) of `Foo`, but I am getting compilation errors like

```
... type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Any
[error]  required: Array[String]
```

So I have a couple questions:

- I am familiar enough with Scala to believe that this is the right way to represent my particular problem, but not familiar enough with it to know how to go about it.  What is the proper way to do what I'm trying to do?
- Also, is there a way to tell class `Qux` that `m` should be treated as the value returned by the specific `method` from `Bar` or `Baz`, and not the abstract method from `Foo`?

*Edit:* Taking the approach suggested by @marios (using abstract type members) seems to be a step in the right direction, but a type mismatch pops up now.  Within the class `Qux`, I now have

```
class Qux[X <: Foo](sc: SparkContext, val foo: X) {
  val m: foo.A = foo.method

  def process(rows: DataFrame) = foo match {
    case Bar(sc, _) => BarProcessor(sc, m).doStuff(rows)
    case Baz(sc, _) => BazProcessor(sc, m.keys).doStuff(rows, m.values)
  }
}
```

Where `BarProcessor` is instantiated with, for instance, an `Array[String]`, and `BazProcessor` needs the key-value pairs from the value returned by `Baz`'s `method` to do stuff.  However, I am now getting errors like

```
[error] Qux.scala:4: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Qux.this.foo.A
[error]  required: Array[String]
[error]     case Bar(sc, _) => BarProcessor(sc, m).doStuff(rows)
[error]                                         ^
```

Similar errors show up when I try to call `Map`-specific methods on `m` when `foo` is a `Baz` (along the lines of `value keys is not a member of Qux.this.foo.A`, etc.).  I understand that `m` isn't *really* an `Array[String]` -- it's of type `A`.  But is there a way to tell Scala to "translate" this into its desired type?

Comment: "type parameter" which can be constrained by a "bound".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easier way to access the individual types in your ADT is to use an **abstract type member** instead of a **generic type parameter**.

```
sealed trait Foo {
   type A
   def method: A
}

case object Bar extends Foo {
   type A = Array[String]
   def method: A = Array.empty[String]
}

case object Baz extends Foo {
   type A = Map[String, Array[String]]
   def method: A = Map.empty[String, Array[String]]
}

case class Qux[X <: Foo](foo: X) {
  def m: X#A = foo.method

  // You can then pattern match on m
  def f = m match {
    case a: Baz.A => a.size // Use Baz#A if Baz is a class and not an object
    case b: Bar.A => b.size // Use Bar#A if Bar is a class and not an object
  }
}
```

Using it (look at the return types)

```
@ Qux(Baz).m
res6: Map[String, Array[String]] = Map()

@ Qux(Bar).m
res7: Array[String] = Array()
```

Comment: This seems to be a very promising approach; thank you!  I am, however, having the compiler complaining to me that "type A is not a member of type parameter X" in the definition of `Qux`.

Comment: Hmmm ... Which version are you using? I tried this on 2.11.8. I just gave it another shot as well.

Comment: Use `:paste` in your shell and then copy paste the entire code. Does that work for you?

Comment: I am also on 2.11.8, and the generic toy code works for me as well.  I was making a dumb mistake in copy/pasting, which resulted in the error I mentioned, but fixing that results in a `private value foo escapes its defining scope as part of type Qux.this.foo.A` pointing to the `def m: foo.A = foo.method` bit..  It's evidently too late in the night here for me to keep working at this, but thank you for your help.

Comment: come back tomorrow ;)

Comment: So I think I am getting that error because class constructor parameters are private by default (correct me if I'm wrong), so replacing `class Qux[X <: Foo](foo: X)` with `class Qux[X <: Foo](val foo: X)` resolves that particular error.

Comment: However, now when I reference `m` later in a function that pattern matches on the subclass of `Foo`, e.g., `foo match { case Bar(_) => // do something with m, expecting it to be an Array[String]` I get a `type mismatch; found: Qux.this.foo.A   required: Array[String]`...

Comment: Can you paste the pattern matching code? I can take a look

Comment: Hi, @marios, thanks for your response.  I made a brief edit at the bottom of the OP.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133937/discussion-between-marios-and-dmdmdmdmdmd).

Answer (score 4):

You could add a type parameter to your trait like this:

```
sealed trait Foo[A] {
  def method: A
}

case class Bar extends Foo[Array[String]] {
  def method: Array[String]
}

case class Baz extends Foo[Map[String, Array[String]]] {
  def method: Map[String, Array[String]]
}
```

Comment: This is the simplest way to do this! Good answer. However, I am not sure if it's really addressing the second part of the question. How would Qux work?

Comment: Add a type class variable to that class as well.  Something like `class Qux[A]`, or maybe `class Qux[_]` if you don't care about the type

Comment: But he does care about the type. `val m = foo.method` the OP wants m to be same type A of `Foo[A]`. I guess something like `class Qux[A](foo: Foo[A])` should do the trick.

Comment: Might be more tricky, thought, if you want to have both the composed types `Bar` `Baz` and their type parameter A. Then you would need to define `class Qux[A, X <: Foo[A]](foo: X)`. You would then have both X (either Bar or Baz) and their type A at hand (say you want to use them as return types of methods in Qux later on).