# Pattern matching with ADTs and type members

Tags: scala, inheritance, types

This is a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41819324/derived-classes-as-class-constructor-parameters).

I have an ADT modeled as follows:

```
sealed trait Foo {
  type A
  def method: A
}

case class Bar(p: T, q: S) extends Foo {
  type A = Array[String]
  def method: A = // implementation
}

case class Baz(p: T, q: S) extends Foo {
  type A = Map[Array[String], Array[String]]
  def method: A = // implementation
}
```

I also have another class that takes a subtype of `Foo` as one of its constructor parameters, and does specific things based on whether it's a `Bar` or `Baz`.

In the accepted answer to the linked question, it was suggested to me by user @marios to implement this idea like so:

```
class Qux[X <: Foo](foo: X) {
  val m: X#A = foo.method

  def process = m match {
    case a: Bar#A => // do stuff with Bar
    case b: Baz#A => // do other stuff with Baz
  }
```

This worked well, but led to warnings regarding unchecked types due to type erasure (since I'm matching on a `Map`, in the case of `Baz`).  In my particular case, though, these were able to be ignored safely.  But I wondered if I could avoid this, and tried to write something like this:

```
class Qux[X <: Foo](foo: X) {
  def process(param: U) = {
    val m: X#A = foo.method
    foo match {
      case Bar(_, _) => BarProcessor(m).doStuff(param) // where BarProcessor expects m to be an Array[String]
      case Baz(_, _) => BazProcessor(m.keys).doStuff(param, m.values) // do related stuff using m, but where m is instead now a Map[Array[String], Array[String]]
    }
  }
}
```

However, in this case I get errors like

```
[error] Qux.scala:4: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : X#A
[error]  required: Array[String]
[error]  case Bar(_, _) => BarProcessor(m).doStuff(rows)
[error]                                 ^
```

My question is, why?  It doesn't seem like these two code snippets are really any different, so why does accessing the type member work in the first case, but not the second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler doesn't even refine type of `foo` depending on the branch (i.e. inside the branch, type of `foo` is still `X`, not `Bar` or `Baz`), much less of `m`. What you can write instead is

```
  def process(param: U) = {
    foo match {
      case foo: Bar => 
        val m = foo.method // m is Bar#A, i.e. Array[String]
        BarProcessor(m).doStuff(param)
      case foo: Baz => 
        val m = foo.method // m is Baz#A, i.e. Map[Array[String], Array[String]]
        BazProcessor(m.keys).doStuff(param, m.values)
    }
  }
```

Note that `foo` in the pattern is actually a fresh variable which shadows the outer `foo`, so this is equivalent to

```
    foo match {
      case bar: Bar => 
        val m = bar.method // m is Bar#A, i.e. Array[String]
        // note that if you use foo here, it still has type Foo
        BarProcessor(m).doStuff(param)
      ...
```